# Receiving a syntax error message of '20WHERE [ID]=2'

Tags: vb.net

In this code I want to update my data but my code is showing a syntax error:

> (Missing operator) in query expression '20WHERE [ID]=2'

in an update query. I'm using an Access database. Here ID is primary key and type is auto number.

[image: Error message]

I don't have any idea what the error is.

```
Private Sub btnADD_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnADD.Click
    Try
        'Open Connection
        If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Open()
        End If
        cmd.Connection = conn

        'cheack save or update
        If Me.txtCusID.Tag & "" = "" Then

            'Insert Data to table
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT Into custbl([CustomerName], [CreateDate], [FormNumber], [AccountNumber], [PhoneNumber], [Gender], [Type], [CustomerType], [Address], [Dist], [State], [Pin], [LoanAmount], [Interest Amount], [ApplicationFeees], [InsuaranceFees], [OthersFees], [ReceivedAmount])" & _
                              " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("CustomerName", CType(txtCusName.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("CreateDate", CType(lblDate.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("FormNumber", CType(txtFormNo.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("AccountNumber", CType(txtAccNum.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("PhoneNumber", CType(txtPnNum.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Gender", CType(cmbGender.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Type", CType(cmbType.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("CustomerType", CType(cmbCusType.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Address", CType(txtAddress.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Dist", CType(txtDist.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("State", CType(txtState.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Pin", CType(txtPin.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("LoanAmount", CType(txtAdcusLoanAmunt.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Interest Amount", CType(txtAdcusInterest.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ApplicationFeees", CType(txtAdcusAppliFees.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("InsuaranceFees", CType(txtAdcusInsurncFees.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("OthersFees", CType(txtAdcusOthersFees.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ReceivedAmount", CType(txtAdcusRecvdAmunt.Text, String)))

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            RefreshData()
            DataClear()
            MsgBox("Successfully Saved!")
        Else
            'Update Data to table
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE custbl set [ID] = '" & txtCusID.Text & "'," & _
                              "[CustomerName] = '" & txtCusName.Text & "'," & _
                              "[FormNumber] = '" & txtFormNo.Text & "'," & _
                              "[AccountNumber] = '" & txtAccNum.Text & "', " & _
                              "[PhoneNumber] = '" & txtPnNum.Text & "'," & _
                              "[Gender] = '" & cmbGender.Text & "'," & _
                              "[Type] = '" & cmbType.Text & "'," & _
                              "[CustomerType] = '" & cmbCusType.Text & "'," & _
                              "[Address] = '" & txtAddress.Text & "'," & _
                              "[Dist] = '" & txtDist.Text & "'," & _
                              "[State] = '" & txtState.Text & "'," & _
                              "[Pin] = '" & txtPin.Text & "'," & _
                              "[LoanAmount] = '" & txtAdcusLoanAmunt.Text & "'," & _
                              "[Interest Amount] = '" & txtAdcusInterest.Text & "'," & _
                              "[ApplicationFeees] = '" & txtAdcusAppliFees.Text & "'," & _
                              "[InsuaranceFees] = '" & txtAdcusInsurncFees.Text & "'," & _
                              "[OthersFees] = " & txtAdcusOthersFees.Text & "" & _
                              "WHERE ID=" & txtCusID.Tag

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            RefreshData()
            DataClear()
            MsgBox("Successfully updated!")
        End If
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)


    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub btnCusAddEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCusAddEdit.Click


    'check for the selected item in list
    If Me.dgvAddCus.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If Me.dgvAddCus.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim intID As Integer = Me.dgvAddCus.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value

            If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

                conn.Open()
            End If
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM custbl " & _
                                                 "WHERE [ID]=" & intID, conn)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)

            Me.txtCusID.Tag = intID
            Me.btnCusAddEdit.Enabled = False
            Me.btnADD.Text = "Update"
            Try
                conn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)

            End Try
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You did the right thing and used parameters for the `INSERT` statement. Do the right thing and use parameters for the `UPDATE` too. Regardless of that, if you can't see the issue then you haven't actually read the error message. In what universe does "20WHERE" have any meaning?

Comment: Possible missing whitespace: `"[OthersFees] = " & txtAdcusOthersFees.Text & " WHERE ID=" & txtCusID.Tag`. Please avoid using string concatenation for SQL values, use parameterized query instead.

Comment: Fun Fact: The `TextBox.Text` is always string and can never be anything else. So all those `CType(..., String)` conversions are pointless

Comment: There's no need to add "please help me" and any similar forms of pleading in your question, _especially in the title_, where it is likely to attract downvotes. This is not Reddit.

Answer (score 2):

If you notice there is no space between the last variable set and `WHERE` clause

```
"[OthersFees] = " & txtAdcusOthersFees.Text & "" & _
"WHERE ID=" & txtCusID.Tag
```

which results in string getting formed as 20WHERE.

For immediate resolution, add space:

```
"[OthersFees] = " & txtAdcusOthersFees.Text & " " & _
"WHERE ID=" & txtCusID.Tag
```

**But**, at the earliest convert this query to **parameterized** as you have done for `Insert` query.

Comment: this code is still more problem , When I update my database there after save button work as update data not save next time. Please Help

Comment: @SuvoGhosh Have you explicitly cleared the txtCustID.Tag after an update? If not, if you have a new record to save, the old ID will still be there and you will get another Update.